# android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable exception at app initialized() on some android devices

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We developed a xamarin forms android app, it's working in some devices and crashing in some devices --> the app will open, after the splash screen appears it is crashing.

It happens on few samsung devices

We found one google console log.

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at SanSmart.App.OnInitialized () [0x00254] in <ce58e5be75db448fa7eb95f3f96a4a6d>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <3a61d48d66dd458fa0b64990b6c8f8cc>:0
at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <3921e1c40bf740cab0f47696b3ad1282>:0
at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <3921e1c40bf740cab0f47696b3ad1282>:0
at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <3921e1c40bf740cab0f47696b3ad1282>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.36(intptr,intptr)
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run (Native Method)
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6986)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: What version of the device crashed？

Comment: Samsung galaxy s9+ with android 9 version

Comment: Did you ever find a cause for this? I am getting a similar error.